# Pre-trained model to recognize residential floor plans?

Tags: dataset, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-datasets, image-recognition, pre-trained-model

Is there a model that, given an image, recognizes whether the image is a floor plan of a residential property? Or a pre-trained, general-purpose model where I could apply transfer learning?

Here's a sample [image](https://hips.hearstapps.com/edc.h-cdn.co/assets/cm/15/04/640x423/54bf3da7e95eb_-_0613200514032646-2.jpg?resize=980:*). Should be quick to train one, but wanted to check whether there's a generally accepted model out there.

Comment: The image link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fastai](https://course.fast.ai/) has pre-trained models for imagenet that you can re-use & transfer learn against. You can probably use a pre-trained resnet network, then retrain it on a dataset you come up with.

Here's one example from the net, but you can search "fastai transfer learning" for more examples: https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-using-the-fastai-library-d686b238213e

The hardest part will be you getting a dataset. [Here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-scrape-google-images-and-build-a-deep-learning-image-dataset-in-12-lines-of-code-b5472f5b5c6) is an example, but I'd honestly recommend working through lesson 1 and 2 of the free [fastai course](https://course.fast.ai/). It'll give you a better overview.

TL;DR - if you can search google for "residential floor plan" or something, you can create a dataset. The hard part will be choosing what non-floor plans to include in your data set. Probably you'll need a lot of random things, but also many things that look *close* to a residential floor plan, but aren't, so it can get good at distinguishing between a floor plan and a maze, and a pinball layout, and a spreadsheet, etc.

Comment: Excellent reply, thank you! I'll check those resources out. Should be a fun quick project.